# Vuex If statement check store.state value in asyncData

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex

I have to use if statement in asyncData.

```
  asyncData(context) {
    if (dataType === 'individual') {
      return fetchPageData(context, 'dashboard');
    } else {
      return fetchPageData(context, 'dashboardCompany');
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      dataType: (state) => state.user.user.type,
    }),
  },
```

this code give me an "error  'dataType' is not defined  no-undef"
when I try this.dataType in asyncData I get "error Unexpected this in asyncData  nuxt/no-this-in-fetch-data"

fetchPageData is plugin with axions.get .json file with data.

Any solution/hint?

Comment: asyncData runs before computed in the lifecycle, which is why dataType is undefined. If dataType is just a store property, you can access the store directly within asyncData instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use computed property on asyncData.

If you wanna use "store" store was included asyncData context.

Comment: I fix this with context.store.state... Not with this.$store